# DWG to image tiles using FME

Tags: tiles, fme-form, google-maps-api, autocad, dwg

I need to make image tiles out of a DWG. I need them so I can use them as overlay on google maps. hopefully I can get them in this folder configuration: `zoom_level/x_or_column/y_or_row.png` or similar cut by 250px by 250px. I tried to follow [an example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gKrFuNFqDbQ) by FME team themselfs and they do not go in details. It was not clear at all.
[Here is the dwg file.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwMirpbclFbreDFabE9QbFpfR2s/view?usp=sharing)
[here is the FME file.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwMirpbclFbreE52aDZnZFpfQm8/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: You should probably rasterize the data BEFORE you try to run it through the WebMapTiler.

Comment: try https://knowledge.safe.com/articles/1099/converting-vector-data-to-raster.html